# How to restrict a incoming URL from Google Search link only for a certain File in a Folder of my application

Tags: google-search, iis7, asp.net-mvc

Google Search displays a link to a file in my application, which is located in a certain folder structure.

I would appreciate if someone help me in knowing how google picked up this file in its search result. (#1)

(#2). I would like to know the method how to avoid a URL hit from certain site to this particular file in this folder.

My application is developed in MVC 3, ASP.NET C#.

Answer (score 2):

1) Google picked it up because it is linked from somewhere. Maybe you posted it on social networking site or had a test site which that was getting indexed by Google. In Google, search using the following to find what other links have been indexed.

```
site:www.yourwebsite.com
```

2) Best way to stop search engines picking it up is by using robots.txt file. If you have a Google webmaster account you can generate one in there for free. For more information read this helpful guide by Google; [Block or remove pages using a robots.txt file](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449)

2 a) If you want everything blocked (users as well) you can use a  [301 redirect](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2010/01/31/how-to-301-permanent-redirect-in-asp-net.aspx)